# difference between conventional analog butterworth filter and that implemented through IIR

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, butterworth

I am confused what is difference between conventional analog butterworth filter and that implemented through digital technique using IIR

Comment: What specifically are you confused about ? What do you think is different ?

Comment: I am confused about their application/performance and scenarios where they are both utilized

Answer (score 1):

If you have designed the IIR Butterworth filter using the **bilinear** transform method, then due to the logarithmic frequency mapping (**warping**), the frequency and phase responses will be distorted...